# grep multiple patterns with differing number of matching groups?

Tags: awk, grep, regular-expression, pattern-matching

I'm trying to tally insertions and deletions from git diffs.

I have the following, which when piped one or more strings of the form `"4 files changed, 629607 insertions(+), 123 deletions(-)"` can tally the total:

```
grep -Eo 'changed, ?(\d+) insertion.*(\d+) deletion' | awk '{ i+=$2; d+=$4 } END { print "insertions: ",i," deletions: ",d }'
```

This produces `insertions:  629607  deletions:  123`

However, sometimes the diff does not follow the above format, but instead only has insertions or only has deletions.

In those cases, instead of matching two numbers, I would only need to match one (and make sure it ends up in the right column).

How can I create a regex that is flexible enough to handle those variations, and that will produce output that `awk` can then correctly tally up?

Comment: [edit] your question to provide sample input that covers all of your use cases ("sometimes...") and the expected output given that input so we can help you. A [single] regexp may not be your best solution and if you want awk to do further processing then you should just do this initial part in the same awk script.

Comment: Why you you use `grep` *and* `awk` when `awk` can also "grep"? Using `awk` only will give you the flexibility you need IMHO.

Comment: I would recommend using [`git diff --numstat` instead of `git diff --stat` for scripts](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_other_diff_formats). The output for `--numstat` is consistent, and its purpose is to be used in scripts. While `--stat`'s purpose is to be human readable.

Comment: @Dan that sounds like it might be worth posting as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `Perl` here for flexibility, readability and portability, there's no complicated regex, let's [`KISS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (...and I use just one pipe from `git`).

It will works in any cases: with or without one of the pattern(s), or this will skip lines that do not match at all:

```
$ git diff
7 insertions, 1 deletions
1 deletions
3 insertions
foobar
```

```
$ git diff | perl -nE '
    BEGIN{our $insert = our $delete = 0}
    $insert += $1 if /(\d+)\s+insertion/;
    $delete += $1 if /(\d+)\s+deletion/;
    END{say $insert . " insertions, " . $delete . " deletions"}
'
```

```
10 insertions, 2 deletions
```

Comment: Very elegant. What does the "$foo //= 0" part do? This seems like a complicated way to put "0" instead of "" in the variable in case no lines matched: could perl have, as awk has, a BEGIN{ }  section to set them to 0 ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I like to use `//=` but true, it's more readable like this now.

Comment: @OlivierDulac, iirc `//` returns the left-hand-side value if it's defined, and otherwise the RHS. It's a bit like `||` in that, except that one checks if the LHS is truthy. (You can see the difference with `0 || "foo"` vs. `0 // "foo"`.) I guess something like  `printf "%d insertions, %d deletions\n", $insertions // 0, $deletions // 0;` would have done the same as the original. (I like `printf` rather than string concatenation for some reason, but it doesn't matter.)

Comment: @ilkkachu: thank you for the additionnal informations. I don't like this "//" notation very much (probably because it looks too similar to C end-line comments ^^).

Answer (score 6):

The other posters have answered how to solve your question directly. However, since you mentioned that you are parsing the result of `git diff`, I would recommend a slightly different approach.

If you want to use the output of `diff` in scripts, you can use [`--numstat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---numstat) instead of `--stat`.

You will end up with a consistent output, as the purpose of `--numstat` is for scripts.

When using `git diff --stat`, you get the following output:

```
$ git diff main --stat
 [...list of files...]
 5 files changed, 112 insertions(+), 20 deletions(-)
```

When using `git diff --statnum`, you get the following output instead:

```
$ git diff main --statnum
-       -       some/binary/file
15      0       some/file
1       1       some/other/file
29      7       another/file
67      12      yet/another/file
```

The structure above is simply a three-columns structure. The first column is the number of insertions, the second column is the number of deletions, and the last column is the filename.

You can sum up the columns by piping the command to `awk` without worrying whether there are or aren't any insertions and/or deletions.

```
$ git diff main --numstat | awk '{sum_insertions+=$1;sum_deletions+=$2}END{print "insertions:", sum_insertions+0, "deletions:", sum_deletions+0;}'
insertions: 112 deletions: 20
```

more links: [git-diff manual page / Other diff formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_other_diff_formats)

Comment: FWIW, `--numstat` works with most git commands that can output commit information. For example, `git dff`, `git log`, `git show`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

`grep` doesn't really provide a good view into capture groups, so I'd just switch to Perl here. With this test input in `foo.txt`:

```
2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
1 file changed, 9 deletions(-)
garbage
1 file changed, 10 insertions(+)
```

you could do:

```
$ perl -ne '/files? changed, (?:(\d+) insertion\S*)? ?(?:(\d+) deletion)?/ && printf "%d %d\n", $1, $2' < foo.txt
2 7
0 9
10 0
```

or do the sums in Perl too:

```
$ perl -ne 'if (/files? changed, (?:(\d+) insertion\S*)? ?(?:(\d+) deletion)?/) { $i += $1; $d += $2 } END { printf "insertions: %d deletions: %d\n", $i, $d }' < foo.txt
insertions: 12 deletions: 16
```

The main point here being that the group for insertions is made optional with the `?` after it, and that the numbering for the capture groups goes from left to right regardless of if they match. Plus some fudging so all three possible input formats match. Of course you could also do two separate matches against `/, (\d+) insertion/` and `/, (\d+) deletion/`, or so.

Answer (score 4):

A GNU awk solution is largely the same as the Perl

```
gawk -F'\n' '
  match($0, /([0-9]+)\s+insertion/, i) { total_i += i[1]; }
  match($0, /([0-9]+)\s+deletion/, d) { total_d += d[1]; }
  END {
    printf("insertions: %d  deletions: %d\n", total_i, total_d);
  }
'
```

POSIX awk doesn't have capture groups, but to avoid any extra `split()` steps can rely on awk to use the initial numeric component
of the matched string and automatically strip the rest in a numeric calculation, i.e. adding "3 insertions" results in adding "3".

```
awk -F'\n' '
  match($0, /[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+insertion/) {
    total_i += substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
  }
  match($0, /[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+deletion/) {
    total_d += substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
  }
  END {
    printf "insertions: %d  deletions: %d\n", total_i, total_d
  }
'
```

If you have a pre-POSIX awk then get a new one but if that's impossible for some reason then change `[[:digit:]]` to `[0-9]` and `[[:space:]]` to `[ \t]` and then that'll work in any awk (except, of course, old broken awk).

Comment: @terdon The initialisation is so the values have a 0 on no match. If there is a better way to default them in the output, then please edit that in.

Comment: No, I don't think there is. You're absolutely right, sorry!

Comment: I just changed `%s` to `%d` so the output is always a number and so the values have a 0 on no match without needing to init them in a BEGIN section. Alternatively you can add zero to the variable to make the result a number before printing - `printf "%s\n", var+0`.

Comment: Minus portability/readability, as you encountered. The GNU version is readable, the POSIX one, less. Perls is consistent across OSes

Comment: @GillesQuénot you can write an awk script that's guaranteed to work in any POSIX compliant box since awk is a mandatory POSIX tool, you can't say the same for perl since it isn't a mandatory POSIX tool. I spent 30+ years working on a system that had mandatory POSIX tools but not perl and it couldn't be installed per policy. We sometimes see questions here and on SO about other such systems. So when you talk about portability for perl scripts it's important to add "if the system has perl".

Comment: Yes, but nowadays, Perl is almost close to everywhere. Maybe not the case before. Rare Unix* OS don't have Perl (you can still install it as user via `perlbrew` with internet connection (USB stick?)). But I tend to prefer readibility over complicated POSIX stuff. Just my point of view. I agree the POSIX awk will be reliable between OSes.

Comment: perl may be almost close to everywhere, I really don't know as I've never used it (probably because it wasn't available the first 30 years of my career til I quit that job), but my point is it's not everywhere and you aren't always allowed to install it, just like you can't always install jq, yq, mlr, python, ruby, xmlstarlet, etc. So IMO that's a caveat when you talk about portability. For some of those tools you can compare robustness for handling specific file formats, but when it comes to portability across Unix systems for general text processing, you can't beat awk as it's everywhere.

Comment: As for readability... your script in this thread is pretty readable (though I personally find the `action if condition` syntax harder to parse than a simple `if condition action`) but my general impression of perl scripts tends to align with https://www.zoitz.com/comics/perl_small.png :-).

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, I've integrated that edit in.  The semi colons are my internal one liner portability lint rule =)